# ASP.NET MVC Post method : Model properties does not persit the value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 ASP.NET MVC action methods, I call the first method by passing and load some initial data, then I get some additional details from UI and call the second action method (`Post` action method from `.cshtml`). The data I received from the first call is missing in the post method. can anyone help me what am I doing wrong or missing here?

Action methods:

```
[Route("setprofile")]
public ActionResult SetProfile(string id)
{
    ProfileData data = new ProfileData();
    //do something
    data.name= getData(id);
    return this.View(data);
}

[Route("setprofile")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetProfile(ProfileData data)
{
    // Here I'm not missing the data.name field value
}
```

View `.cshtml` file:

```
<div class="panel-body">
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetProfile", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div>
    <h3> Name: @(this.Model.name)</h3>
</div>
<h3>
    Comments:@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.comments)
</h3>
}
```

I get the comments value but not getting the name field value from the model here.

Note: I need to display the value I received from the first action method as a label, not text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things, Name is writen as text and in order to send back to server, you need to put it inside input element.

IF you dont want to show it `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.name)` creates hidden input element.

Other than this, check `ModelState` for validation errors..

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     return BadRequest(ModelState);

.... your code here
```

if your model is not valid, the `ProfileData` returns  result

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added an `input` element for it to be sent back to the server when the form is submitted. If you don't want it to be visible, whilst still being posted back, add a hidden field for it:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.name)
```

Without that, all you're doing is rendering `name` to the markup but, once the form is submitted, it won't be sent back. Alternatively, you could render a textbox for the value whilst setting its `readonly` attribute. That would allow it to be visible, not changed, and still be sent back to the server.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```